# Found the adress of a function LIBC without GDB

Tags: libc

How to calculate the address of a function in the LIBC, when ASLR is not active.
I only have the address where to load the LIBC (with `ldd /bin/bash`).

Thank you for the explanations

**EDIT:**

When I use your method I do not get the good result, although it is good in general (I do not understand why)

libc base adress

`ldd ch33
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7fff000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7e46000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80000000)`

system offset:

`gdb -q /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
gdb$ print system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x40310 <__libc_system>`

I then calculate `0x40310 + 0xb7e46000 = 0xb7e86310`

However, i should get `0xb7e64310`

because:
`~$ gdb ch33
gdb$ r
Starting program: /challenge/app-systeme/ch33/ch33
...
gdb$ p system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xb7e64310 <__libc_system>`

Comment: Did you found an answer for this, I also get randomized addresses for libc functions. I checked ASLR in my system its disabled + binary is compiled with -fno-stack-protector flag so I don't know why libc addresses changes, did you found an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using

objdump:

```
$ objdump -TC /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep " printf$"

0000000000064e80 g    DF .text  00000000000000c3  GLIBC_2.2.5 printf
```

readelf:

```
$ readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep " printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5"
   627: 0000000000064e80   195 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

nm:

```
$ nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep " printf$"
0000000000064e80 T printf
```

gdb:

```
$ ldd ./shellpointcode               
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3f1e1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3f9213f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3f92732000)
$ gdb -q /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
pwndbg: loaded 171 commands. Type pwndbg [filter] for a list.
pwndbg: created $rebase, $ida gdb functions (can be used with print/break)
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so...done.
done.
pwndbg> print printf
$1 = {int (const char *, ...)} 0x64e80 <__printf>
```

Then the effective address of `printf` would be

```
0x64e80+0x7f3f9213f000 = 0x7f3f921a3e80
```

Comment: This method does not work, I edited my message to see

Comment: The title of the question says “without gdb”

Comment: @ken The loading addresses are different sometimes in gdb and ldd although idk why

Comment: @SYS_V I have edited the answer to keed gdb as the last option.